# Mocked inner objects' events will not fire?

Tags: c#, events, recursion, moq

Using **Moq** with two interfaces,`Outer` and `Inner`, I am unable to get `Outer.Inner.SomeEvent` to fire.

```
public interface Outer
{
    Inner Inner { get; }
}

public interface Inner
{
    int Prop { get; set; }
    event EventHandler PropChanged;
}

public void Test()
{
    Mock<Outer> omock = new Mock<Outer>();
    Mock<Inner> imock = new Mock<Inner>();

    Console.WriteLine("Inner");
    imock.Object.PropChanged += InnerPropChanged;
    imock.Raise(m => m.PropChanged += null, EventArgs.Empty);
    imock.Object.PropChanged -= InnerPropChanged;

    // This has no effect.
    //omock.Setup(m => m.Inner).Returns(imock.Object);

    Console.WriteLine("Outer");
    // Both the auto recursive and the explicit above produce the same behavior.
    omock.SetupProperty(m => m.Inner.Prop, -1);
    omock.Object.Inner.PropChanged += InnerPropChanged;
    omock.Raise(m => m.Inner.PropChanged += null, EventArgs.Empty);
}

public void InnerPropChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("  InnerPropChanged");
}
```

Output when calling `Test()`:

```
Inner
  InnerPropChanged
Outer
```

How can I alert subscribers to any of `Inner`'s events? Nothing seems to be able to fire them.

Edit - To clarify, I want to be able to raise the `Inner` event from the `Outer` context, so the final output should include:

```
Outer
  InnerPropChanged
```

Comment: Hmmmm, everything looks right :( have you tried omock.SetupProperty(m => m.Inner, imock.Object)?

Comment: Why do you want to raise the event through the Outer. Why don't just just `imock.Raise(m => m.PropChanged += null, EventArgs.Empty);`?

Comment: @nemesv Because I want Moq to handle the recursive setup without creating explicit `Inner`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's bug or a missing feature that the expression

```
omock.Raise(m => m.Inner.PropChanged += null, EventArgs.Empty);
```

is not working... however you can get the generated the `Inner` mock with `Mock.Get` and then you can raise the event on it:

```
public void Test()
{
    Mock<Outer> omock = new Mock<Outer>();
    Console.WriteLine("Outer");
    omock.SetupProperty(m => m.Inner.Prop, -1);
    omock.Object.Inner.PropChanged += InnerPropChanged;
    Mock.Get(omock.Object.Inner)
        .Raise(m => m.PropChanged += null, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Which produces your desired output:

```
Outer
  InnerPropChanged
```

Comment: I'm inclined to think it's a bug, considering that the second "events" example in the docs is: `mock.Raise(m => m.Child.First.FooEvent += null, new FooEventArgs(fooValue));` ("Raising an event on a descendant down the hierarchy") as per http://code.google.com/p/moq/wiki/QuickStart#Events